# How to create Omniauth user and session in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, omniauth

In some of my Rspec tests, I need to sign in a user. I am currently using Omniauth for this but am not sure how to do this in a testing framework.

How would I go about authenticating and creating users via Omniauth and signing them in with Rspec. I imagine to create the user, I could just call the create_with_omniauth method:

```
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
        create! do |user|
            user.provider = auth["provider"]
            user.uid = auth["uid"]
            user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
            end
end
```

But that doesn't answer the question of how to sign in the user.

Answer (score 2):

the good thing about omniauth is, that you don't have to care about it most of the time.

when you want to do controller tests (i assume you want to do that because you are talking about sessions), just stub the call to your `current_user`.

i'm using omniauth and rspec in my project, you might find that useful: https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/blob/master/spec/controllers/likes_controller_spec.rb#L16-L18

Comment: I tried out stubbing, and the test still wasn't able to find a button that is only there if the user is signed in. Here is a link to controller test if that helps: https://github.com/afuhrtrumpet/menu_app/blob/make-integration-tests/spec/requests/restaurant_pages_spec.rb

Comment: so you are talking about capybara integration testing? that is a completely different game then... when asking questions on stackoverflow it is fundamental to give enough context!